# Substitution Variables & &&

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am preparing for the Oracle certification. While I was going through the basic level Queries I came across the Substitution Variable. My doubt here is,

1. If we create a query with the Substitution variables, How can a front user can understand the required field?
2. And are we not creating any confusion with this inputs?
3. How better we can optimize this type of queries?

Please provide your valuable suggestion.

Thank you in advance

Comment: are you sure this should be categorized as MySQL, and not Oracle?

Comment: I mean to say its an Oracle SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first two points, it sounds like you need the SQL*Plus [`accept`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve005.htm) and [`prompt`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve032.htm) commands; they are further explained under [Receiving a Substitution Variable Value](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#sthref494). Those together will allow you to explain what the value the user is asked to enter is for, which I think addresses the 'confusion' part too.

`accept` also automatically defines the variable, so the user won't be prompted for it again even if you use a single ampersand (`&` rather than `&&`).

```
prompt The next value you will be asked for should be numeric
accept badVarName prompt 'Enter some value: '
select ... from my_table where my_column = &badVarName;
```

I'm not sure what kind of optimisation you're referring to, but you could use a bind variable in your query instead, possibly populating that from a substitution variable:

```
variable bindVar number;
exec :bindVar := &badVarName;
select ... from my_table where my_column = :bindVar;
```